# Read xlsx file into python without losing information

Tags: python, excel

**The goal is to read in an xlsx file into python. All information provided is just to give context to the problem.**

In these examples, the date read in should be `2004/07/01`

#### How the data looks in "LibreCalc"

Here's what librecalc displays

```
12/30/99
12/30/99
...
```

Here's what the actual cell formulas are defined as.

```
=Date(2004,7,1)
=Date(2004,7,1)
...
```

## Pandas

#### CASE 1 (`pd.read_excel`)

Displayed results

```
00:00:00
00:00:00
...
```

`values` function returns

```
array([datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 0), ...,
       datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 0)],
      dtype=object)
```

#### CASE 2 (`pd.read_excel(..., parse_date)`

Displayed results

```
2020-04-14
2020-04-14
...
```

`values` function returns

```
array(['2020-04-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-04-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-14T00:00:00.000000000', ...,
       '2020-04-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-04-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-14T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Which is today's date, not `2004/7/1`

---

So the problem seems to beyond a simply reformatting the values. It looks python doesn't have any idea how to parse the dates.

---

[image]

Comment: what data do you lose in case 3? you had only dates in Excel and in that case you have dates in pandas. i don't see the problem here.

Comment: Do you mean `case 2`? The date should say `2004/01/07` but it reads in all dates as being today regardless of the value in the `xlsx` file.

Comment: I updated the problem to try making it more clear. Everything should be interpreted as `2004/01/07` but in the first case, it just says everything is 0, and in the second case, it says everything is today's date.

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem: i created Excel file with two rows with dates like `=DATE(1999;12;12)`. I saved the file as `dates.xlsx` and opened using `pandas` with: `data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\dates.xlsx', header=None)`. And everything works fine - I got nice DataFrame with the same dates as in Excel (even with `timestamp` format!).

Comment: Did you use Date=(2004,4,4) or did you use Date=(2004;4;4)? I’ll go back and see if I can reproduce the error on another file with precise instructions if that doesn’t mess things up.

Comment: I really appreciate you looking into this! It’s very much appreciated :)

Comment: I used a semicolon, but I have my local non-english version of Excel. I think in English version there are comas. But I wouldn't worry - if you use wrong separators in Excel it would tell you that. Anyway, try with super simple example (just like mine) - maybe the error is somewhere else?

Comment: Have the formulas that define the dates been evaluated?  Excel only caches the result of a formula after the sheet has been (re)calculated and then saved.  Why is LibreCalc displaying "12/30/99" rather than 2004-07-01 (or 07/01/04)?  I'd solve the second question before worrying about Python.

Comment: @oco If I click on the cell, add and delete a character, than it fixes what is displayed. Maybe it's how librecalc buffers? Data in there looks good

Comment: This is crazy. If I copy and paste the document over to a new file and resave it as the same file type, then I can read it in just fine... I'm going to keep digging but that's crazy

Comment: The cells that I "refreshed" by just adding a space and deleting it are able to be read in just fine. All the ones that I haven't done that too, can't be read in properly. I need to figure out how to do that for all the cells in mall my files...

Answer (score 0):

my dudes, if I run "find and replace" and just find "=Date(" and replace it with "=Date(" then everything works. I have like 40 files I need to do that to but it's manageable. That's insane. Why in the world would this work?